# Choosing map projection type for flight plan

Tags: coordinate-system, maps

There are two projection of maps that I saw online. UK CAA is a transverse projection map, while ICAO maps are conical.

It seems that transverse map is easier for flight planing as straight lines are rhumb lines, on the other hand the shortest route between two point is the great circle which is curved. So it's easy to calculate a heading, but it will not be the best route.

In conical map the straight lines are the Great circles so the best route, but its harder to calculate heading for flight.

What should be choosen and why? I didn't found info about this on the Internet...

Comment: I would think that in the most used transverse cylindrical projections the rhumb lines are not straight, just as in the conics the geodesic lines are not straight. I do not know the maps you are referring to, but perhaps it would be good to include a link to them to clarify the projections. Regarding the preference, i understand that the corresponding routes and headings are calculated analytically, so the map where they are displayed may not matter.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This seems more an issue of personal preference, since you can't obtain both properties in a single map.

Comment: Consider a Two-point equidistant projection, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/395766/88814